# how to create a 128MB HFS+ partition using diskutil

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, disk-format

I have a ~ 500GB disk in my new Mac, and I would like to create a 128MB HFS+ (Journaled) partition using OS X, but when I tried to do this earlier today the smallest HFS+ partition I could create was 1GB.  This partition needs to be only a couple hundred MB big because it's only going to be storing GRUB bootloader, i.e. a boot.efi file and some other small files, so when I hold the "option" key while booting I can boot into the appropriate Linux distribution I have setup.  Is it possible to create a 128MB partition with a HFS+ filesystem?  I would prefer to used the "diskutil" command line program over using the GUI app "Disk utility".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up booting into an ArchLinux live environment, and created a 128MB partition using "cgdisk" then installed [hfsprogs](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/hfsprogs/).  After that I was able to format the partition using mkfs.hfsplus.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible with diskutil command line:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/diskutil.8.html